# Can an Airport Express act as AP and AirPlay at the same time?

Tags: airport, airplay

I know it's possible to have an Airport Express create a wireless network by connecting it to my router (through enthernet cable).

But can it act as AirPlay at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is in fact the purpose of the AirPlay feature. Just plug it to your stereo or active speaker with the jack on the rear. A small "airplay" icon (see the example on the [Apple homepage](http://www.apple.com/airplay/)) will appear appear in iTunes or iPhone/iPad when you play music. You can then select whether you want your music on the Airport Express router or on your computer / iDevice.